# Accessing Google Analytics Reports using the API

Tags: google-analytics

I know how to use the Google API to access different metrics and dimensions to query for specific data. However, I am faced with a different scenario. I would like to know if there is any mechanism to access the reports/custom reports that are already created using the Google Analytics web user interface.

Our client has created about 15 different reports and now wants us to simply get the data into his own database rather than having to log into the Google Analytics website and run the report and export the data.

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are thinking, but you can always use the Reporting API to extract the data using python/javascript/etc and then store the data locally in your database. For more info, check out the [Google Analytics Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) and try out different combinations of dimensions and metrics to be able to extract the data. You can then use any number of different [Core Reporting API Client libraries](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries) to access the analytics database.