# Individual visitor flow from Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to get a visitor flow associated with a given ga:transactionId through the Google Analytics API?

There's limited availability in ga:landingPagePath, ga:secondPagePath, ga:exitPagePath and ga:pageDepth

but a more complete path would be desirable

Thanks!

Comment: Try out http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Answer (score 2):

You can access the flow with the `ga:previousPagePath` and `ga:pagePath` dimensions and the `ga:visits` metric. You can play around with the output in the Query Explorer. For what its worth, here are a few of other related questions:

- [Get Google Analytics "Visitors Flow" data from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502062/get-google-analytics-visitors-flow-data-from-api)
- [Accessing Google Analytics Reports using the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173187/accessing-google-analytics-reports-using-the-api)
- [How to extract engagement flow data using google analytics reporting api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553782/how-to-extract-engagement-flow-data-using-google-analytics-reporting-api)